# Reset vuforia ground plane position

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, vuforia

I'm working on an iOS app using Unity and Vuforia ground plane. The app has multiple scenes. In the first scene I automatically place my content using ground plane and everything works fine.

The problem is in the second scene. If I turn and want position my content in the second scene at somewhere else, it always automatically appears on the plane created in the first scene. I assumed tracking would reset when I load a new scene but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Does anyone know how to force the tracking to reset at the start of a scene?

Comment: In Vuforia PositionalDeviceTracker class has two methods Reset() and ResetAnchors(). Using PositionalDeviceTracker can be tricky though. You have to use TrackerManager to get the instance of running positional device tracker.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Just to clarify, I have added this to the Plane Finder in my scene. 

PositionalDeviceTracker tracker;

 private void Start()
    {

        tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.InitTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();
        tracker.Reset();
        tracker.ResetAnchors();
       
 }

It doesn't seem to be working however. Can you spot anything that I might have missed?

Comment: Can you spot if your positional device tracker is null or not? or download Vuforia samples from unity asses store. It has a virtual buttons example scene there you can find a TrackableSettings.cs Then you can see how they used Positional Device Tracker

Comment: Thanks! I re-downloaded the Core Samples and realised in the Plane Manager script there is a function called ResetTrackers(). It was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have found a solution for the issue.

```
 private StateManager stateManager;
 void OnVuforiaStarted()
 {
    Debug.Log("OnVuforiaStarted() called.");

    stateManager = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager();

 }

 private void DestroyAnchors()
 {
    IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> trackableBehaviours = stateManager.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours();


    foreach (TrackableBehaviour behaviour in trackableBehaviours)
    {
        Debug.Log(behaviour.TrackableName);
        stateManager.DestroyTrackableBehavioursForTrackable(behaviour.Trackable,true);

    }

 }
```